# How to save and read text file or MHT format file in Android Q and above Version

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-external-storage

How to save and read MHT format files or any format files in Android Q and Above version to External storage. As know that `getexternalstoragepublicdirectory()` is deprecated and one solution to this is using `getexternalfilesdir()` but saving files using `getexternalfilesdir()` the files will be deleted when the app is uninstall, and i want all files are to be saved permanently.

Any example or guide will be more helpful :)

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) and [this series of blog posts](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html).

Comment: With Storage Access Framework the problem is that it allow user to save the file where they want to save it, but in my case i want to save the file in a specific directory because i'm also accessing all the user saved files within the app

Comment: "it allow user to save the file where they want to save it" -- from the user's perspective, this is a feature, not a bug. "in my case i want to save the file in a specific directory" -- that is not possible on Android 10+, sorry. "i'm also accessing all the user saved files within the app" -- and all of those files will be in this one location. So, save the `Uri` to the document tree (e.g., in `SharedPreferences`) and use `takePerisistableUriPermission()` to have long-term access to that document tree.